# Implementing idempotency for AWS Spot Instance Requests

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using the Java AWS SDK to make EC2 spot instance requests. As opposed to on demand instances, the [API for spot requests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-RequestSpotInstances.html) does not have anything similar to [`ClientToken`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Run_Instance_Idempotency.html) and thus does not support idempotency out of the box.

The most straightforward way I could think of to do this was to set the `LaunchGroup` property to a unique UUID; when I check for that I call [`DescribeSpotInstanceRequests`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeSpotInstanceRequests.html) and see if I already have a request with the same launch group.

To my surprise, it seems that there's a delay before the describe call returns the spot requests sent before. I wrote a JUnit test for this and it seems that in order for it to be consistent I would have to set a timeout of at least 60s between the two calls (request spot instance and describe spot instance requests). I need to have a granularity of 10s, because my requests can get repeated by the application at this interval, in case of any failure - i.e. something breaks after I sent the request but before I could read the result I got back from Amazon. In that case I don't want to have the request repeated, I just want to see that it got registered and move on.

```
@Test
public void testRunSpotInstances() throws Exception {

    activity.execute(execution);

    timeout(TIMEOUT);

    // shouldn't do anything
    activity.execute(execution);

    timeout(TIMEOUT);

    DescribeSpotInstanceRequestsResult result = client.describeSpotInstanceRequests(
            new DescribeSpotInstanceRequestsRequest().withFilters(new Filter()
                .withName("launch-group").withValues(BUSINESS_KEY)));

    assertThat(result.getSpotInstanceRequests()).hasSize(1);

    timeout(TIMEOUT);
}
```

The test works every time if TIMEOUT is set to 60s; for 40-50s it works intermittently. Anything below this fails every time.

Has anyone managed to work around this delay? Is implementing idempotency for spot requests possible using just the AWS API and not having state saved in the client application?

Comment: To add a bit more context to this question: This is part of the work we are doing on Axemblr Provisionr - a service that can help you create pools of virtual machines. https://github.com/axemblr/axemblr-provisionr

Comment: Interesting issue - I can't add anything constructive currently other than confirming that I've encountered various similar API delays in the context of the [Bamboo AWS Plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/774227) and concluded that the AWS API needs to the treated as being [_eventually consistent_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) only across the board; e.g., I've even encountered cases where I received a resource id from a create call, could tag the resource  based on its id but not describe it thereafter still, because it supposedly doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: Thanks Steffen! I hope things will improve over time.

Comment: Great idea on using LaunchGroup for ensuring idempotency of request

Answer (score 0):

> In that case I don't want to have the request repeated, I just want to see that it got registered and move on.

If you got a 200 back, then it's registered.  It may not show up right away, but it's registered and you can move on in your flow.

> Is implementing idempotency for spot requests possible using just the AWS API and not having state saved in the client application?

I don't believe so.  I have the same sort of issue with Amazon's EMR.  The way that I work around it is to have a component who's job it is to observe clusters.  When I make a request for an EMR cluster, I get back a cluster id, which I then pass off to some observer.  The observer will then call my other components when that cluster changes state.  Not being acknowledged by EMR right away is a valid case and is not treated like an exception.

I have no idea if that's appropriate for you.  Perhaps you could try maintaining the [SpotInstanceRequestId](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/SpotInstanceRequest.html#getSpotInstanceRequestId%28%29).  In my case, I only keep them in memory, but you could keep them somewhere persistent if need be.