# Deterministically creating and tagging EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am creating 3 EC2 instances, and subsequently iterating and tagging each of them.
Sometimes the tag request fails, although the instance later appears to be running.

Could this be a timing issue? Should I wait a few seconds after creating the instance before tagging it? Is there a deterministic way to wait for it to start?

Comment: Its possible, what error do you get when it fails? Its also possible that the API just failed and would succeed on a retry.

Comment: @datasage - I get that the EC2 instance doesn't exist. I guess retry would work, but I suspect it's because the instance hasn't completed registering by the time the call to create it completed.

Comment: Parts of AWS are probably best considered to be eventually consistent. I would retry with a delay of some sort.

Comment: Have you considered using an AWS Cloud formation template to create the EC2 instances? This allows for Tagging to be set upon execution/creation of the resource. They can also be invoked via CLI/API calls.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update 20140512

AWS has meanwhile added more detailed documentation on [Troubleshooting API Request Errors](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/query-api-troubleshooting.html),  including a section addressing [Eventual Consistency](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/query-api-troubleshooting.html#eventual-consistency), which basically confirms the analysis in my initial answer below:

> The Amazon EC2 API follows an eventual consistency model, due to the distributed nature of the system supporting the API. **This means that the result of an API command you run that affects your Amazon EC2 resources might not be immediately visible to all subsequent commands you run**. [...]
>
> [...] For example, [...] **if you run a command to modify or describe the resource that you just created, its ID might not have propagated throughout the system, and you will get an error responding that the resource does not exist**.
>
> To manage eventual consistency, you can do the following:
>
> - Confirm the state of the resource before you run a command to modify it. **Run the appropriate Describe command using an exponential backoff
>   algorithm** to ensure that you allow enough time for the previous
>   command to propagate through the system. [...]
> - **Add wait time between subsequent commands, even if a Describe command returns an accurate response**. Apply an exponential backoff
>   algorithm starting with a couple of seconds of wait time, and increase
>   gradually up to about five minutes of wait time.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

**Please note**: Most [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/) meanwhile apply these suggestions automatically, including options to adjust the default retry policy or add a custom implementation even - see [Error Retries and Exponential Backoff in AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) for guidance on how to implement it yourself, if need be.

---

### Update 20130719

The eventually consistent design of the AWS API is increasingly encountered by various large scale AWS users, who naturally need to look deeper and work around it accordingly, see for example the following articles:

- [Dealing with Eventual Consistency in the AWS EC2 API](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2013/06/18/dealing-with-eventual-consistency-in-the-aws-ec2-api/) (by Martin Englund, Cloud Foundry)
- [Dealing with the Inconsistent EC2 API](http://blog.picloud.com/2013/02/17/dealing-with-the-inconsistent-ec2-api/) (by Aaron Staley, PiCloud)

---

### Initial Answer

As already [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15865894/deterministically-creating-and-tagging-ec2-instances#comment22583637_15865894) by @datasage, the AWS APIs apparently need to be generally treated as [eventually consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) only - this is certainly unexpected when first encountered, but actually not too surprising for a large scale service in hindsight, i.e. an engineering resp. operational tradeoff to address the [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem).

See also my comment on Alex Ciminian's question [Implementing idempotency for AWS Spot Instance Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734882/implementing-idempotency-for-aws-spot-instance-requests#comment20644231_14734882), where he discusses his test results regarding similar consistency issues:

> Interesting issue - [...] I've encountered various similar API delays in
> the context of the [Bamboo AWS Plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/774227) and concluded that the AWS API
> needs to the treated as being [eventually consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) only across the
> board; e.g., I've even encountered cases where I received a resource
> id from a create call, could tag the resource based on its id but not
> describe it thereafter still, because it supposedly doesn't exist
> (yet).

- What I describe here seems to indicate that each and every single API action is operated entirely independently by AWS in fact (and not only across the externally visible services, but even within a single one like EC2), thus can suffer from eventual consistency and must be treated accordingly.

For details on the mentioned cases you might want to look into [Frequent polling of AWS API causes throttle limit](https://bitbucket.org/utoolity/bamboo-aws-plugin/issue/2/frequent-polling-of-aws-api-causes), where I summarize our analysis and approach to improve the handling via the available but limited retry/backoff functionality within the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/) - the solution is all but ideal, but it seems to considerably improve things for the time being.

On a similar note, the redesigned [AWS SDK for PHP 2](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) introduced dedicated *“Waiter” objects that allow you to poll a resource until it is in a desired state* to address the problem, see section *Waiters* within the [Quick Start](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/guide/latest/quick-start.html#waiters) for details:

> One of the high-level abstractions provided by the SDK is the concept
> of “waiters”. Waiters help make it easier to work with eventually
> consistent systems by providing an easy way to wait on a resource to
> enter into a particular state by polling the resource. [...] Any
> @method tag that starts with “waitUntil” will utilize a waiter.
>
> ```
> $client->waitUntil('BucketExists', array('Bucket' => 'my-bucket'));
> ```

Comment: Thanks for a great response. I've just started working against the EC2 API, and was surprise by this behavior. I think I understand the approach from an operational sense, but from a software perspective, it's feels like a hack to push back the state management outside of the API. At the end of the day, we all have to tell someone that the  site is up and running. Maybe you don't have to do this if you have a couple hundred servers in a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Tag name cannot be created until the instance is launched . You might try giving the key_name while creating the instance. If you are using boto, it could be done by

```
reservation = conn.run_instances(1, 1, instance_type='m1.small', key_name='samplename')
```

Then instances can be retrieved by passing key_name and once they are in running state, you can also give them the tag name.